# Grant tfs build to execute sharepoint cmdlet

Tags: service-application, tfs, build

I use TFS Build which is configured with a service account.

I've modified the worklow template to execute a powershell script.

The powershell is launched but on sharepoint cmdlet I have an "access denied error".

So I tested the script with run as different user (using tfs build service account) and it works.

The tfs service account SpShelleAdmin, local admin and farm admin.

I need help.

PS : Get-SpSolution works